# which is correct - in section below or below section

Tags: language-formation

We have given detail description of these tools in below section.
or
We have given detail description of these tools in section below.

which one is correct?

Comment: Either works; both require an article. "In **the** section below" or "In **the** below section". I'd say the former is more common and less clunky than the latter, and in either case I would prefer "*following*" to "*below*"; but that's just me talking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is acceptable in UK English, provided that you to put a 'the' in there:

*"We have given detailed descriptions of these tools in **the** below section."*

or:

*"We have given detailed descriptions of these tools in **the** section below."*

or even:

*"We have given detailed descriptions of these tools in **the** following section."*

If you search google for the term 'the below section', you find many official UK and US documents which use it:

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22the+below+section%22+filetype:pdf